# How to re-apply all previous calculations in a pandas data frame on append

Tags: python, pandas, append, apply

Let's say I have this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[4,5,6]})
```

And let's say I define a new column like this:

```
df["C"] = df["A"] + df["B"]
```

then the `C` column will have the values `[5, 7, 9]`.

However, let's say I append a new row with the values `4` for `A` and `7` for `B`, then the `C` column will have the values `[5, 7, 9, NaN]`.

How can I define the columns that the calculation rule is automatically applied when something is added to the data frame? Or is there a "recalculate all" function of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

What distinguish Python from other programming languages is that it is interpreted rather than compiled. It means that the code is executed line by line.

So, in your case when you'll add a row at the end of the `df`, there will be no *re-calculation*.

```
df["C"] = df["A"] + df["B"] #executed firstly

df.loc[len(df.index)] = [4, 7, np.NaN] #executed secondly

print(df)
     A    B    C
0  1.0  4.0  5.0
1  2.0  5.0  7.0
2  3.0  6.0  9.0
3  4.0  7.0  NaN
```

Unless you force the re-calculation yourself by adding the same line as before :

```
df["C"] = df["A"] + df["B"]

df.loc[len(df.index)] = [4, 7, np.NaN]

df["C"] = df["A"] + df["B"] # <------added here to re-calculate
​
print(df)
     A    B     C
0  1.0  4.0   5.0
1  2.0  5.0   7.0
2  3.0  6.0   9.0
3  4.0  7.0  11.0
```

If you're using a notebook like [`Jupyter`](https://deepnote.com/?utm_source=google-ads&utm_campaign=Jupyter-Conversions-Europe&utm_agid=139609835179&utm_term=jupyter%20alternative&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=612630713712&gclid=CjwKCAiAhKycBhAQEiwAgf19ekSfP1smfRe4RSNDpcs5yLDRVDJpD5fVZz2uaoAN15YNGLcHfnThSBoCFC4QAvD_BwE&gclid=CjwKCAiAhKycBhAQEiwAgf19ekSfP1smfRe4RSNDpcs5yLDRVDJpD5fVZz2uaoAN15YNGLcHfnThSBoCFC4QAvD_BwE), you'll need to put `df["C"] = df["A"] + df["B"]` in a separate cell and re-run it after each row appended/added.